# Python find similar files in given folder

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function which will find similar files by a name (song.mp3, song1.mp3, (1)song.mp3) in a specified folder. What I have by now:

```
def print_duplicates(source):
    files_list = []
    new_list = []

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
        for fname in filenames:
            if ('\w*' + fname + '\w*') in files_list:
                new_list.append(os.path.join(dirpath, fname))
            else:
                files_list.append(fname)

    for a in new_list:
        print(a)
```

If the filename wasn't before in files_list it will be added, if it was than it will be added to new_list with its path. This way I have list of 'duplicate' files. However it's not working, the new_list remains empty.

Could you correct my mistakes? Which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use regex but you've not actually made use of the regex functions. `str in str` won't take any notice of regex syntax.

Comment: do you mean given three files in a directory - `song.mp3 , song1.mp3 , (1)song.mp3` you want 1 of them in files_list and the rest in new_list?

Comment: can you add an example of input and expected output as your question is pretty unclear

Comment: Ok, let's assune that there's a one folder with files test.txt, test1.txt and 1test.txt. I want my program to give my path to test1.txt and 1test.txt, because i know that they are duplicates of test.txt, but have a little bit different name. Then, I want to delete these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use regex in your code, you need to use `re` module.

So change this line,

```
if ('\w*' + fname + '\w*') in files_list:
```

to,

```
if re.search(r'\w*' + fname + r'\w*', files_list):
```

which is exactly same as,

```
if fname in file_list:
```

because `\w*` means zero or more word characters.  And I think you want to use word boundaries.

```
if re.search(r'\b' + fname + r'\b', files_list):
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however how can I use re.search with lists? TypeError: expected string or buffer.

Comment: try this, `[re.search(r'regex', i).group()  for i in lst] `